# In using Dirichlet's test to show that an integral converges, I seem to have to use Dirichlet's test again,

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

The integral I am looking at is

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac {\cos(ax)}{x+b}dx$$

for $a,b>0.$

In the integration by parts -- Dirichlet's test -- the integration term is:

$$\frac {1}{a} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(ax)}{(x+b)^2}dx$$

What do I do now?  Looks like it requires yet another application of Dirichlet's test, but of course we know that this is a $p$-integral, with $p=2$, so that the integral converges.

Do I just conclude this integral converges, without going further?  This is not homework - just for my own practice.

Thanks,

Comment: You also have to check whether the limit $$lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{sin(ax)}{a(x+b)}$$ exists, which is the case here.

Comment: But then, it is sufficient to verify the convergence of the second integral.

Comment: Yes.  The second integral, obtained by IBP, is not only convergent, but also absolutely convergent.

Comment: The limit for $x \rightarrow 0$ even exists if $b=0$, so you should have no problems here.

Comment: Right @Dr.MV, which makes me think of something I wanted to ask you.  In all of the comparison tests, the usual online and many textbook references always require decreasing summands / integrands.  But I think we can relax those requirements and only require that the summands and integrands *eventually* are monotonically decreasing  down to zero -- such as this integrand, oscillating for just a bit, before it clearly decreases monotonically.  Do you agree?  After all, it's only the tail-end of the sequences that we need to be concerned with to assess convergence.

Comment: Assuming no singularities, as x (or n) go to infinity, that is.

Comment: It is the tail end unless there is a singularity along the way.  However, we need not require that the integrand approaches zero to guarantee convergence.  The quintessential example is $$\int_1^\infty \cos(x^2)\,dx$$which converges as can be easily shown by substituting $x^2\to x$.  Then the integral transforms to $$\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos x}{2\sqrt{x}}\,dx$$which converges by Abel's test.

Comment: Abel's test and Dirichlet's test are the same thing, right @Dr.MV?  And, wow, this is such a cool example.  Thanks so much for showing this.  So there is no such thing as a requirement for an "nth term" test for integral convergence.

Comment: You're welcome.  It was my pleasure. - Mark